# Encountering error "The NTVDM CPU has encountered an illegal instruction" while using pointer

Tags: c++, c

While creating a program for mergesort, i encountered an error while using pointer instead of array. The following code runs correctly:

```
void main()
{
    clrscr();
    int n,i,A[100];
    cout<<"Enter the value of n: ";
    cin>>n;
    cout<<"\nEnter the array: ";
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        cin>>A[i];
    mergesort(A,0,n-1);
    cout<<"Sorted array is: ";
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        cout<<A[i]<<" ";
    getch();
}
```

But when i replace A[100] by *A in main i.e. when main definition becomes following:

```
void main()
{
    clrscr();
    int n,i,*A;
    cout<<"Enter the value of n: ";
    cin>>n;
    cout<<"\nEnter the array: ";
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        cin>>A[i];
    mergesort(A,0,n-1);
    cout<<"Sorted array is: ";
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        cout<<A[i]<<" ";
    getch();
}
```

then also program gives correct output, but before exiting the console window it gives the error "**The NTVDM CPU has encountered an illegal instruction**". When i put array input code in separate function then i don't get the above error i.e. when code becomes following:

```
int getList(int* A)
{
    int n;
    cout<<"\nEnter the value of n: ";
        cin>>n;
    cout<<"\nEnter the array: ";
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        cin>>A[i];
    return n;
}

void main()
{
    clrscr();
    int n,*A;
    n=getList(A);
    mergesort(A,0,n-1);
    cout<<"Sorted array is: ";
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        cout<<A[i]<<" ";
    getch();
}
```

then i don't get illegal instruction error. Can somebody please help?

Comment: There just no point left in using a 16-bit C compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared a pointer, `int *A`, but no memory for it to point to.
After you declare it, add

```
A = malloc(100 * sizeof(int));
```

and before main exits, add:

```
free(A);
```

When you transition from static arrays to using dynamic memory (and therefore using pointers explicitly), you need to allocate your memory manually.

Also, it's good form to assign a pointer to NULL when you declare it:

```
int *A = NULL;
```

This will make debugging easier - you'll get a null pointer exception when you try to dereference the pointer, instead of a random error when your memory gets corrupted.

On a side note, malloc can fail (it will return NULL). Thus, you should do a check on A after the malloc call:

```
if (NULL == A) {

  // do some error handling

}
```